# Notepad++ can't download files

Tags: ftp, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ v6.7.8.2 with the NppFTP plugin.
I can access my server files, but when I try to download them I get,

```
-> CWD /public_html/cuislegibney/css
250 OK. Current directory is /public_html/cuislegibney/css
-> PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (69,195,124,244,160,170)
-> LIST
150 Accepted data connection
226-Options: -a -l
226 3 matches total
-> TYPE I
227 Entering Passive Mode (69,195,124,244,182,25)
-> SIZE /public_html/cuislegibney/css/stylesheet.css
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
-> PASV
213 4855
Download of /public_html/cuislegibney/css/stylesheet.css failed
```

All of the above message is green except for the final line.

Previously when I clicked on a file it would open in a new tab. How can I get it to do this again?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you download the file with a vanilla ftp client

Comment: Isn't a client trying to create another TCP connection (on 2-nd PASV) while a server allows a single TCP connection?